# Is there a way to link in a stylesheet where the extension is not .css?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I need to dynamically link in the CSS (and JS if you know - haven't tested) but when I do that the browser is not rendering the styles?

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test"/>
```

If I manually upload and save the file as test.css it then works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css"/>
```

Is there a way to say to the browser, "This is a CSS file. Please disregard that it doesn't have a css extension"?

**MORE**
The reason is I'm setting up a server that allows the user to create their own CSS dynamically. I'm storing this information in a database and don't want to create a physical (digital) file each time the user updates the css or a new user creates their account. So, the URL might be, href="http://somedomain.com/home.php?user=453&css=true" or something like that and that, if placed in the URL of the browser, would return the raw CSS.

Comment: Is there some restriction in place that you cannot give your CSS files the proper extension? It seems like a simpler solution to the problem...

Comment: I've never seen this done; why would you remove the `.css` extension from a CSS file (genuinely curious)?

Comment: As long as the server sends it as a CSS file, you should be OK, but I don't know if you can set up a server to send files as a certain type if they don't already have some sort of extension to map too. The bigger problem I see is that how is someone else going to update your code base in the future without extensions? That sounds really messy.

Comment: if it is to use a php file that is rebuild each time it's called, use header() to send mime type

Comment: @Chris - It's so I can link to a server side script to get CSS from the database rather than a physical file (not physical but digital obviously).

Comment: Just realized if I'm loading it dynamically I can probably append a query with something like, "my_CSS_Generating_Page.php?something=something.css" so the last characters in the URL are ".css".

Comment: Since you're using PHP, you can easily use `header("Content-Type: text/css");` to set the correct MIME type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Browsers look in the first place at the MIME-type of the content they receive, this is in principle independent of the extension of the file. The MIME type is sent by the web server as part of the HTTP header (the envelope of the file, if you will.)

The correct MIME type for CSS stylesheets is `text/css`. If stylesheet files have the text/css MIME type (defined in the HTTP header), your browser will use them to apply the styles no matter what the extension.

If the MIME type is wrong, the result is undefined: it depends on the browser and the HTML version & strictness if the style gets rendered or not. You can check the MIME type by using your browser's debugger.

See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECJXB.png) for an example in Chrome.

[image: this screenshot]

Each paragraph has `color: red` rule in the corresponding file, but one isn't applied. As you can see, the style in the text/plain file does get rendered, although its MIME type is not correct. The browser does give a warning. The style in the text/html file generated by PHP is not rendered (and a warning is given.)

PHP and other scripting engines allow to manipulate the MIME type however, as I have done in the test.css.fixed.php file (code below.) As you can see, the browser no longer complains and applies the styles regardless of its extension.

In PHP, the MIME type can be set as follows (this is test.css.fixed.php):

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: text/css");
?>

    p.test_css_fixed_php {
        color: red;
    }
```

The `header` function changes the HTTP header that is sent by the server.

If you don't work with a scripting engine, you can configure your web server to set the MIME type correctly (see e.g. [Apache mod_mime configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html)).

Note that the HTML version and strictness also have influence on this. In Chrome, styles in a text/html file seem to get rendered anyway when the HTML type is not strict. But you cannot count on that, so it's a quick & dirty fix at best.

Comment: After reading this I checked and there is a way to set the mime type on the link tag on the client side. There is. It's the type attribute. I set it to "text/css" but it was not applied. The browser doesn't recognize it as css which I'm guessing is a bug on their part. I'll try setting the headers. "+1" or "thanks"

Comment: The HTML5 standard actually requires the user agent to prioritize the MIME type sent by the server over the MIME type set as link type attribute on the client. You can read about this [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-link-element.html#attr-link-type), which covers your case explicitly. The client-side attribute is meant to prevent the user agent from downloading file types it doesn't support (e.g. not download VB scripts if it doesn't support VB script execution.)

Answer (score 0):

i think the extension is not a problem - it can be any extension. try adding a dot - maybe that will work `css/test.`

Answer (score -2):

Any CSS file will need to have the CSS file extension. That is how HTML will know that the file is meant to be used as a stylesheet. Otherwise, it is just a bunch of plain-text characters with no meaning.

Comment: No. File extension does not determine content. That's what MIME types are for. For example: `image.jpg` might actually be a PNG.

Comment: This is incorrect - it's not required. See [wkampmann's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21067379/836214) for details on why.